# Develop vs code extension to edit text

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to build an extension that edits all the links in a file in the editor. If should be something like this

BEFORE:

```
<img src="assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.jpg" alt="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/uikit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

AFTER:

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/images/avatars/avatar-1.jpg' %}" alt="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/icons.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/uikit.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
```

This is the code of my extension.js file so far

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('auto-django.autoDjango', function () {

        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
        const selection = editor.selection
        const text = editor.document.getText(selection)

        var regexp = /<img[^>]+src\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]+)['"][^>]*>/g;

        var match = regexp.exec(text);
        var src = match[1];

        const newText = `{% static '${src}' %}`

        editor.edit(builder => builder.replace(selection, newText))
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

And all this code does is that it takes the first image src link and changes it to the edited link, that is good, but it also replaces it with the whole text in the editor.

But what i want to do is that it should just replace with each of the links in the editor.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: why use `editor.selection` if you want to change stuff in the whole file, get the complete text of the file, find the positions of the strings to replace add them all to the EditBuilder with the replace text, use a different register command to already get an editor and EditBuilder in the callback

Comment: The problem is, how do i do that?

Comment: Like, how do i get the position of the strings?

Comment: your regex match has that position, use that offset to convert it to a line:char `vscode.Position` with the `editor.document`

Comment: pls can you draft out a demo code, im kinda new to this

Answer (score 1):

First thing I see:

`editor.document.getText(some Range)` takes a `Range` not a `Selection` - that is why it is returning all the document text - it does that when the argument is invalid.

`editor.document.getText(new vscode.Range(selection.start, selection.end))`

should get you the text of the selection.